# Failed to resolve: com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.4.0

Tags: android, firebase

These are the dependencies in my app gradle file. How can I resolve the error?

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:11.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.4.0'
    androidTestCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: have you pasted googleService.json to your project

Comment: Yes, I have pasted the JSON file, into my app folder.

Comment: then try solutions mentioned below

Comment: @SayanSahoo Welcome to Stack Overflow. Check the answers given below and mark the best answer as accepted if it solves your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Include this in your **root-level**(not the app level) bulid.gradle file:

```
allprojects {
    // ...
    repositories {
        // ...
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com" // Google's Maven repository
        }
    }
}
```

For more instructions check the [Firebase Integration Guide.](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup)

Comment: Affter pasting them I am getting these errors No resource identifier found for attribute 'layout_constraintTop_toTopOf' in package 'com.example.sayan.appfire' No resource identifier found for attribute 'layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf' in package 'com.example.sayan.appfire'

Comment: You might have removed the constraint layout dependency. post your both build.gradle files.

Comment: Root level Dependencies
dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com" // Google's Maven repository
        }
    }
}

Comment: dependencies {
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:11.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.4.0'
    androidTestCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}

Comment: Add `compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'` in as a dependency in your app level build.gradle file.

Comment: You have used `androidTestCompile` instead of just `compile`.

Comment: Thanks Buddy, it works :)

Answer (score 2):

Add `maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }` to your root level `build.gradle` file

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: After pasting them I am getting these errors 
 No resource identifier found for attribute 'layout_constraintTop_toTopOf' in package 'com.example.sayan.appfire'
No resource identifier found for attribute 'layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf' in package 'com.example.sayan.appfire'

Comment: Add dependency in your build.gradle file

`compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'`

Comment: I already have it written over there. But still I am getting these errors!

Comment: ohh Sorry! Yeah It works thanks :D

Comment: No problem, I'm glad :)